# Auto Generate Email Based On Username In Wordpress For New Users

Tags: wordpress, checkout, user-registration

i am trying to add a function in my website which allow customers to avoid the email if they don't have any email, like many of my customers have no emails, so what i want, if they come to my site place an order and move to checkout page they can enter their details and put a username for account creation, and then email should be automatically added to Email Field.
For example, if my customer typed his username as Kashif975 the email field should be filled with Kashif975@xyz.abc

the given snippet is working fine, but what the issue, if client have an email and he entered the email but when he start typing in username field the client's email override with auto generated email
can any one help me to what code should be so this problem get resolved
the auto fill function should work only if client don't put the email

```js
    $(document).on( "input", "#user_login", function AutoEmail() {
        var x= $('#user_login').val();
      if( x != "" ) {
          $('#email').val(x+'@xyz.abc');
      } else {
         $('#email').val("");
      }
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Username: <input type = "text" id = "user_login"><br>
Email: <input type = "text" id = "email">
```

Comment: For a start, try using `"change"` rather than `"input"`. Then it won't do it on every keypress. Next, try putting the email field first. Finally, you check if the username is empty (I would use `var username = ` not `var x=` — what does `x` mean?) but you need to also check if email is empty `if( x != "" &&  $('#email').val() == "")`

Comment: actually i have copied this code from somewhere in stackoverflow,  i used below code in header in wordpress,
  $(document).on( "input", "#account_username", function AutoEmail() {
        var x= $('#account_username').val();
      if( x != "" ) {
          $('#billing_email').val(x+'@gamela.st');
      } else {
         $('#billing_email').val("");
      }
       
    });
actually i am not a developer, can you please rewrite the full code for me? please?